# How might an Ubuntu machine that has full-drive encryption be altered remotely to enable remote reboot?

Tags: ssh, encryption, reboot, luks

I've got a remote machine that was set up with full-drive encryption. I need to remotely reboot the thing. Is there some way to remotely alter the machine such that the passcode for decryption gets entered before boot, or some way to remotely remove the encryption? I know all of these things go against the security model, but the thing needs rebooting and I don't have in-person access to it.

Comment: No. What is the point of enryption, if anyone can just disable it remotely?

Comment: Someone who has physical access to the machine needs to connect it to a KVM-over-IP device. Thus, if you connect remotely to the KVM device (not to the machine itself), you will be able to enter encryption password. Probably you can achieve similar result if the machine has a built-in remote managament feature (like iLO on HP servers).

Comment: @mikewhatever As I said in the question, I am aware that what I want to do undermines the security model. My purpose is not security, it is to get a remote machine rebooted.

Comment: Boot the machine using iLO (HP) iDRAC (Dell) etc.. as per @raj's comment.  (which I believe is more of an answer and how I'd try doing it; ie. the *probably you can achieve* as I guess Raj hasn't tested it; neither have I either sorry)